# Intellij line breaking after moving files

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm using Kotlin, Spring Framework and as I refactor my codes I found out that Intellij automatically inserts a line break to where moved classes are used. I moved classes to newly created package and the class(which has not been moved) that uses these classes gets new auto line break at where the classes are used.

This doesn't seem to be a lint problem that I don't know what is going wrong. This works this way only on my Intellij not on others'. Is there any way I can stop auto line breaking after moving classes??

Comment: Can you add screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Disable the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | On Save | **Ensure every saved file ends with a line break** option.